# How to recover stock firmware on the Galaxy Note 3

Tags: samsung-kies, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-3

How do I restore stock firmware.  I have firmware upgrade encountered an issue.  Please select recovery mode in Kies and try again.  I am using KIES 3 because I have a Samsung Note 3 N900A and it won't connect.

Comment: So, just to confirm... You can't connect your Note 3 with Kies 3?

Answer (score 1):

- Restart your phone in ODIN mode by pressing Volume Down + Home + Power
- Register and download your stock firmware from sammobile.com
- Unzip the downloaded firmware
- Download ODIN from xda-developers
- Don't uninstall Kies as you'll need the driver
- Open ODIN and connect your phone to computer (Phone should be in ODIN mode)
- When your phone is detected it will be listed under comX
- Under PDA select the extracted firmware you downloaded (Select the file with .tar.md5)
- Only the checkbox for PDA, Auto reboot and F. Reset time should be checked
- Click start to start your flashing
- Your phone should reboot with stock firmware

Note: You'll lose all the offline content from your phone

Comment: Thanks for the information about SamMobile.com. I'd been looking for a place to download stock firmware. Happy Easter to you, too!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a `n900-cwm-recovery-6.0.4.7-kk(0125).tar`
2. Open Odin
3. Add the file from step #1 and click start

WAIT TILL PASS##